FreeRTOS+FReeRTOS-PLUS - как правильно создать проект и заставить сетевой стек работать
Всем добра!
Пробую сделать проект в STMCubeIDE для stm32f767zitx, чтобы на нем отладить TCP/IP обмен.
Создаю новый С проект, добавляю в него FreeRTOS - все хорошо, проект собирается. Для контроля добавляю Task, в которой моргаю светодиодами (спасибо коллегам, показали как).
Добавляю в него FreeRTOS-PLUS, в свойствах проекта
gcc ... -D STM32F7xx=1

как указано в NetworkInterface/readme.md, и получаю много ошибок, в том числе
#error For what part should this be compiled?

хотя флаг я добавил; много ошибок вида:
'ETH_DMADescTypeDef' {aka 'struct <anonymous>'} has no member named 'Status'

После того как руками добавил в файл srm32fxx_hal_eth.h строку:
#define STM32F7xx

вижу:
undefined reference to `HAL_ETH_IRQHandler'

хотя в файле stm32fxx_hal_eth.c тело функции вроде есть.
Буду признателен за помощь, ибо пока не понимаю, как лечить проблему.
